# Trouble trying to find the newest date of a file in a folder with VB6

Tags: vb6

I need to find the file that has the newest date in a given directory. I'm *less* than a beginner in VB6 and that's what I need to use for some old code. After killing Google all day below is what I have so far. But it doesnt find the right file. Can someone help please?
Thanks

```
Dim sFile1  As String
Dim sFile2 As String
Dim dFile1Date As Date
Dim dFile2Date As Date

sFile1 = Dir("c:\test\*.*", vbNormal)

Do
    sFile2 = Dir
    If sFile1 <> "" Then dFile1Date = FileDateTime("c:\test\" & sFile1)
    If sFile2 <> "" Then dFile2Date = FileDateTime("c:\test\" & sFile2)

    If dFile1Date > dFile2Date Then sFile2 = sFile1

Loop Until sFile2 = ""

FormVersionDate = sFile1
Call MsgBox(FormVersionDate, vbExclamation, App.Title)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you step through your code, you'll see that `sFile1` never gets reassigned no matter what the results of your logic, so calling it's value at the end makes all of your do loop irrelevant. Also it looks like `FormVersionDate` is probably supposed to be a date, but you're assign a string to it instead.

I re-wrote your code with nested looping to avoid logic if it was irrelevant with excessive commenting:

```
Dim sFile1  As String
Dim sFile2 As String
Dim dFile1Date As Date
Dim dFile2Date As Date

'Get first File
sFile1 = Dir("c:\test\*.*", vbNormal)
'Make sure file exists
If sFile1 <> "" Then
    'Since file exists retrieve DateTime for file
    dFile1Date = FileDateTime("c:\test\" & sFile1)
    'begin loop for other files
    Do
        'Retrieve new file
        sFile2 = Dir
        'Make sure file exists
        If sFile2 <> "" Then
            'Retrieve DateTime for file
            dFile2Date = FileDateTime("c:\test\" & sFile2)
            'If old DateTime is older than new DateTime
            If dFile1Date < dFile2Date Then
                'Overwrite first file variables with newer file info
                sFile1 = sFile2
                dFile1Date = dFile2Date
            End If
        End If
        'Loop until new file doesn't exist
    Loop Until sFile2 = ""
End If
'If you actually want the date, you should use dFile1Date instead of sFile1.
FormVersionDate = sFile1
Call MsgBox(FormVersionDate, vbExclamation, App.Title)
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the detailed explantion as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot to be said for trying to communicate through variable names.  Often the result is far clearer than adding a raft of compensating comments, especially in a short procedure.

```
Dim Directory As String
Dim CurrFile As String
Dim CurrDate As Date
Dim NewestDate As Date
Dim NewestFile As String

Directory = "c:\test\"
CurrFile = Dir$(Directory & "*.*", vbNormal)
Do While Len(CurrFile) > 0
    CurrDate = FileDateTime(Directory & CurrFile)
    If CurrDate > NewestDate Then
        NewestDate = CurrDate
        NewestFile = CurrFile
    End If
    CurrFile = Dir$()
Loop
MsgBox CStr(NewestDate) & vbNewLine & NewestFile
```

Note that this doesn't detect and warn about a directory with no visible files in it however.  You could just look for an empty ("") `NewestFile` though.