# Get name of lastest modified file in folder

Tags: vb6

Lets say I have a folder called "C:\", in this folder there are numerous .txt files with names like "0001", "0002", "0003" etc. How would I go about getting the file name of the last modified / edited file into a variable?

Im using Visual Basic 6.

Cheers

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and what is and what was wrong. Errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble trying to find the newest date of a file in a folder with VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316749/trouble-trying-to-find-the-newest-date-of-a-file-in-a-folder-with-vb6)

Answer (score 1):

Best to use the FileSystemObject in VB6   You will have to reference it.  Goto Projects > References. Find and check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

```
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim objFile As File
Dim strPath As String
Dim strLastFile As String
Dim dCompareDate As Date


strPath = "C:\"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

dCompareDate = CDate("1/1/1900")

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    If objFile.DateLastModified > dCompareDate Then
        dCompareDate = objFile.DateLastModified
        strLastFile = objFile.Name
    End If

Next

Debug.Print strLastFile
```